# Объединение (с наложением, пересечением) map на основе "близости" C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Всем привет!
У меня есть данные, которые хранятся в `map<double, string>`(Это финансовые данные, double цена, а string имя актива)

Я получаю новые данные в таком же формате. Возник вопрос, как их склеить вместе?
Чтобы при склейке  эти string данные делали append (то есть чтобы символы наслаивались друг на друга). Вот примерная иллюстрация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

фишка тут вот в чем, обратите внимание на данные которые приходят, то есть 220.8 лежит *"примерно рядом"* с 221 и буковка A склеивается с C в одну строку.
тоже самое с 219.5.

Не могу придумать как такое сделать. Версия C++ 17

После этой манипуляции мы получаем как бы распределение активов.

**UPD** Моя попытка решения

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>



void show_data_in_console(const std::map<double, std::string>& data)
{

    std::cout << "\n\t DATA \n\t" << std::endl;
    for (const auto& p : data)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " \t" << p.second << std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    std::map<double, std::string> data;

    data = {
            {219,"C"},
            {220, "C"},
            {221, "C"},
    };

    std::map<double, std::string> new_data;

    new_data = {
            {219.5, "A"},
            {220,"A"},
            {220.8,"A"},
            {222,"A"},
            {223,"A"},
    };

    for (auto const& v : new_data)
    {
        if ( data.find(v.first) == data.end() )
        {
            // not found key so add it
            data[v.first] = v.second;
        }
        else
        {
            // found key so update it
            auto new_value = data.at(v.first);
            // append new tpo symbol to old symbol
            new_value.append(v.second);
            // update data in map
            data[v.first] = new_value;
        }
    }


    show_data_in_console(data);

}
```

Возможно, важное уточнение, ключей в такой штуке может быть много, а вот высота столбика с символами ограничена 24 символами (на картинке выше высота столбика 219 - 2 символа)

**UPD 2**

все уже придумано до нас :) Ответ на поставленный мной вопрос вот это -
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Квантование_(обработка_сигналов)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2))

Comment: Для начала надо сформулировать размытое "примерно рядом" в строгих математических терминах.

Comment: @gbg думаю округление к ближайшему целому подойдет

Answer (score 2):

Заводите [multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) с ключем по `int32_t` или даже `int64_t`, при помещении в него данных домножайте на 10 в нужной степени. Все "склеится" само.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, привести пример кода? Не очень ясно, что за нужная степень и где ее брать. Обновил пост, с попыткой моего решения.

Comment: @SergoLongid, если вас интересует только одна цифра дробной части, то умножайте на 10, если 2, то на 100, если только целая часть, то на 1. Надеюсь, понятно?

Comment: @avp Хорошо, допустим я умножаю 10.5 на 10 и получаю 105, получается ключ 105 (он улетит очень  далеко от ключа 11)

Comment: @SergoLongid. вы не учли, что умножаете все. Т.о. ключ 11 превращается в 110

Comment: @avp спасибо я разобрался, все что мне было нужно это вот это - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Квантование_(обработка_сигналов)